# InfoWindow not showing above Marker Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have created a jsFiddle demonstrating my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/6vpc2/1/
Hover over the marker in my jsFiddle to see InfoWindow placement.

I have a GoogleMap "object" the creates Google Maps. After creating a Google Map like so:

```
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8, // The initial zoom level when your map loads (0-20)
    minZoom: 6, // Minimum zoom level allowed (0-20)
    maxZoom: 17, // Maximum soom level allowed (0-20)
    zoomControl: true, // Set to true if using zoomControlOptions below, or false to remove all zoom controls.
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT // Change to SMALL to force just the + and - buttons.
    },
    //center: location, // Centre the Map to our coordinates variable
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // Set the type of Map
    scrollwheel: false, // Disable Mouse Scroll zooming (Essential for responsive sites!)
    // All of the below are set to true by default, so simply remove if set to true:
    panControl: false, // Set to false to disable
    mapTypeControl: false, // Disable Map/Satellite switch
    scaleControl: false, // Set to false to hide scale
    streetViewControl: false, // Set to disable to hide street view
    overviewMapControl: false, // Set to false to remove overview control
    rotateControl: false // Set to false to disable rotate control
}

if (this.instances.length > 0) {
    return this.instances.pop();
}

var googleMap = new GoogleMap();
googleMap.map = new google.maps.Map(googleMap.mapCanvas, mapOptions);
return googleMap;
```

I then set a var in a JS "object" to the returned googleMap value.

Then I use this.map, which is the returned googleMap from the above code, to set a marker on the map:

```
 this.latitude = latitude;
this.longitude = longitude;

var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: placeMarkerContent
});

this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: this.map,
});

this.map.setCenter(location);

google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    infowindow.open(this.map, this.marker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    infowindow.close(this.map, this.marker);
});
```

The problem is the InfoWindow does not show above the Marker, see my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vpc2/1/
Hover over the marker in my jsFiddle to see InfoWindow placement.

Comment: this.marker is undefined when you are using it in the mouseover listener.  Inside the click listener function, "this" is the marker.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vpc2/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: You rock man! You exactly right, just changed this.marker to this and all is well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.marker is undefined when you are using it in the mouseover listener. Inside the click listener function, "this" is the marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    infowindow.open(this.getMap(), this);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vpc2/3/embedded/result/)